# How to add the CSRF token to a form submission in ApostropheCMS

Tags: csrf, apostrophe-cms

In the documentation is described how to exclude routes from CSRF protection, but I would prefer to include them. Is there a way to add the CSRF token into a hidden field, what name should it have?

Scanning through source code I only see a header that is added to AJAX calls, does this mean than in the current version regular POST calls aren't possible to make safe?

Answer (score 1):

We could have allowed a hidden field to be used, but a hidden field is less safe than a header because a third party phishing site is permitted to submit regular POST forms, but it is not permitted to add HTTP headers to requests. So the standard protection covers you in two ways: (1) the attacker can't access the CSRF cookie, and (2) the attacker can't add a header either because only JavaScript can add headers and JavaScript is subject to the same-origin policy.

Thus using a jQuery form submission rather than "plain vanilla" POST is best practice for ApostropheCMS.

However jQuery form submissions are very easy anyway and they work better; you don't have to render an entirely new page for the user, for one thing.

Here is a simple example of jQuery code to enhance an ordinary HTML form:

```
$(function() {
  var $myForm = $('.my-form');
  $myForm.on('submit', function() {
    $.post($myForm.attr('action'), $myForm.serialize(), function() {
      // It worked, now display a thank you message, or navigate somewhere
    }).fail(function() {
      // An error was received, show the user a message etc.
    });
    // IMPORTANT: prevent the traditional submission
    return false;
  });
});
```

Here I am pulling the URL to POST the form to from the action attribute but you don't have to do that, you can use any URL that is set up to receive a POST form submission.

Note that I did not do anything special to get AJAX protection here. As long as you use jQuery's AJAX mechanisms (including `$.post`), it is automatic with ApostropheCMS.

You can fill in my success and fail functions here with code to show or hide messages already embedded in your page, etc.

Edit: here is a possible workaround to make it work the way you want it to.

```
// Browser-side JavaScript
$('form').each(function() {
  $(this).append('<input type="hidden" name="xsrf-token" value="' + $.cookie(apos.csrfCookieName) + '" />');
});
```

Now, in `lib/modules/your-module/index.js`, you can supply middleware to put this hidden field where Apostrophe expects it:

```
self.expressMiddleware = {
  when: 'beforeRequired',
  middleware: function(req, res, next) {
    if (!(req.body && req.body['xsrf-token'])) {
      return next();
    }
    req.headers['X-XSRF-TOKEN'] = req.body['xsrf-token'];
    return next();
  }
};
```

Comment: I don't follow, I might not understand it full. As far as I know csrf tokens in hidden input are a standard practice in many web frameworks, they are also accepted when being pen tested. Since the user has to have the CSRF token in session or cookie this prevents third parties posting. Only when user clicks posts the form in their own browser the csrf token will match. What am I missing, how is the attack you describe carried out?

Comment: You're right about situations where the cookie is unique and that is apostrophe's default behavior. So we could support this. We also support a more efficient mode where we rely solely on the fact that javascript can't set headers unless permitted by same-origin; in that situation my point is more relevant.

Comment: I'm going to add a possible workaround to my answer.

Comment: Thanks! I was playng with such solutions, but keep running into the fact that the body seems to not be parsed before forbidden is triggered. Was thinking of putting it in as a query params for now

Comment: Oh right, the body parser runs after that. You could use the csrfExceptions feature and also roll your own.